# How to import Panel configuration from versionned code

Tags: 6, panels, importing-exporting

I have a Panel in my D6 website and I have exported it using the Panels Export Section and I want to know if it is possible to use this code from i a module so I can have a version control over the Panel configuration.
How can I do that. Is there any Panle API I can use??Or how can I export panel export in features??

Thanks

Comment: I think you can do this with Strongarm, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: OK I will try to find out how. Thks

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module.

Comment: I have yet tried it but features says Panels are exported via another component or modules but i can't find which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Panels Import](http://drupal.org/project/panels_import) or [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module. I think it's a best way for you.